# Can you change / update routes in a ASP.NET Core 7 app after startup?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am working on implementing a CMS and one portion of that is changing the site's structure - specifically **after** the site has finished starting up.

In older versions of ASP.NET MVC, you could basically build up a new routing table and essentially replace the running routes.

I do not see how to do this in ASP.NET Core 7. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm curious about this myself. You might make some headway by looking into the route specification code in startup, and see if the underlying structures can be modified later somehow.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could consider using the `MapDynamicControllerRoute` to achieve your requirement. The MapDynamicControllerRoute is used to rebuild the route. Inside the MapDynamicControllerRoute class you could read the appsetting.json file. Since the appsettings.json will reload if we modify it. So it let us modify the route after startup complete or you could write the logic to read  the route from the database.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

appsetings add a route template:

```
"Router": {
    "Controller": "Home",
    "Action": "Privacy"
  }
```

DefaultValueTransformer Class:

```
public class DefaultValueTransformer : DynamicRouteValueTransformer
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public DefaultValueTransformer(IConfiguration configuration) {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public override async ValueTask<RouteValueDictionary> TransformAsync(HttpContext httpContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {

        var controller = _configuration.GetSection("Router").GetValue<string>("Controller");
        var action = _configuration.GetSection("Router").GetValue<string>("Action");

     ;

        values["controller"] = controller;
        values["action"] = action;
        

        return values;
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
app.MapDynamicControllerRoute<DefaultValueTransformer>("{**url}");

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Result:

[image]